# How to i chop a comma delimited text file and put the results in a listbox?

Tags: c#

This is my code and data, i was able to read and load the first column

Name,Surname,Gender,Age

Queeneth,Sefoka,Female,33

```
string path = @"c:\temp\Data.txt";
        
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
{
    string s;
    int Pos;
    string col1,col2,col3,col4;
     
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {                     
        Pos = s.IndexOf(',');                    
        if (Pos != -1)
        {
            col1 = s.Substring(0, Pos);                      
            listBox1.Items.Add(col1 );
        }              
    }      
}
```

Comment: A csv is normally a tabular thing (multiple lines with multiple columns). How should that fit into a Listbox that is just showing a List? Show an example what you have as input file and how it should look in the Listbox.

Comment: my data : Name,Surname,Gender,Age   so  on the listbox it should load the first column (Name) without the comma  second colunm same thing till the last column..

Comment: Unless you really need to you should always use File.ReadAlLines; then enumerate them and do a Split(',') on each and add the Items. Usually a ListView is way better suited for you task, ie to display multiple columns..